# Export php data array to csv - conflict with identical variables

Tags: php, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I've set up a data array which is used to write a CSV file. Everything works fine, except the problem that I have to use a certain variable (e.g. "name_c") serveral times in the CSV file.

The array looks like:

```
 public function prepareModeData($intForm, $arrToSave)
 {
    $arrData = array();
    $arrData['name_a'] = 'A';
    $arrData['name_b'] = 'B';
    $arrData['name_c'] = 'this';
    $arrData['name_c'] = 'is a';
    $arrData['name_c'] = 'test';
 }
```

When creating the CSV file like this:

```
 public function generateModeCSV($arrData, $strContent)
 {
    foreach ($arrData as $k => $v) {
        $strContent .= utf8_decode($k) . ';' . utf8_decode($v) . "\n";
    }
    return $strContent;
 }
```

The output in the CSV file is like:

```
name_a;A
name_b;B
name_c;test
```

But I need something like this and can't figure it out:

```
name_a;A
name_b;B
name_c;this
name_c;is a
name_c;test
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: `$arrData = [['name_a','A'],
['name_b','B'],
['name_c','this'],
['name_c','is a'],
['name_c','test`'],];`.... and then loop through using `fputcsv()` rather than trying to write your own csv writer

Comment: I know it's not the "best way" to do it as described and I could add an if statement to the output function but I thought there must be another way to solve the problem.

Comment: An array cannot contain the sane index serveral times. So $arrData['name_c'] is `test` after prepareModeData call

Comment: This isn't anything to do with "best way"; it's about your misunderstanding of arrays... array keys __must__ be unique.... as per the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): `If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.`

Comment: **I got it, thanks four your advice!** But how could I modify the generateModeCSV funnction to get the result I need?

Comment: There's no way you can.... not until you've produced a valid array that contains what you need

Comment: Try building the array using `$arrData[] = ['name_a', 'A'];` etc

Comment: Thank you very much, your information helped a lot! :) One last question concerning the array - is it possible to mix different types of elements in an array? E.g. `$arrData[] = ['name_a', 'A'];'

Comment: combined with `$arrData['name_b'] = 'B';`